# Asp Literal won't disappear after refreshing the page?

Tags: asp.net, database, refresh, hide, asp-literal

I have aspx page with asp Literal.
It's the control page, and literal will show message, when data has been saved to database, (after pressing SAVE button).

It work, but after i have saved and trying to refresh page, the literal text won't disappear... 
Is there any nice and easy way to hide literal text after refreshing the page?

I have tried jquery `.hide` method, but i have faced another problems with that.

In front page `script` i have this value:

```
        Literall.text="Saved!!!"
```

And end of the page i have this:

```
        <h2 style="color:red;">
            <asp:Literal id="Literall" Text="" runat="server"/>
        </h2>
```

Comment: Perhaps using of popup is better way?

Comment: It might be... I have to thing about it, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `EnableViewState="False"` on the `Literal1` markup:

```
<asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" id="Literall" Text="" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: It won't disappear with that... :(

Comment: It's end of the sql command script. It's over 400 rows, so i won't post it all in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjYzW/). Is that what you mean?

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing the whole code. But if `Literall.text="Saved!!!"` is executed in the button event handler it should not be a problem. If you put that in the `Page_Load`, that might be the problem.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MjYzW/2/) is whole code, sorry, but it's in Finnish. In HTML Literal part is in line `132` and in script `273`. Script is in `<head>` and html code is in `<body>`

Comment: I see no problem in your code :(; But disabling viewstate really works; See [this little aspx page](http://jsfiddle.net/yB7HW/). If you click on the `Save` button it will show you the notification, if you click other button, the notification will be invisible just as desired. I suspect you are re-submitting the page multiple times. Note that pressing `F5` or `CTRL+R` re-submits the page in which case your `lomake` method runs multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

put `Literall.Text="";` in page load event

Comment: Do you mean this? `<%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" Trace = "false" UICulture="fi"  Literall.Text="" Culture="fi-fi" debug=true %>`

Comment: what actually i meant is you just add this in your page load event if(!IsPostback())
{
 Literall.Text="";
}